# Use multiple Assets route in Play Framework 2

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0, assets

I had this route in my application:

```
GET    /assets/*file   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I used reverse route in a scala template and it worked properly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.css")">
```

But when I add this route for images:

```
GET   /images/*file   controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file)
```

I get following error in scala template that worked properly:

```
not enough arguments for method at: (path: String, file: String)play.api.mvc.Call.
Unspecified value parameter file.
```

I can not use controllers.Assets.at twice in route in Play Framework 2 or something else?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/Assets), I believe you can add 1 or more routes for your assets.

Here is the important part that I think you missed:

> This action will look-up the file and serve it, if it exists.
>
> Note, if you define asset mappings outside “public,” you’ll need to
>   tell sbt about it, e.g. if you want:

```
GET  /assets/*file               Assets.at("public", file)
GET  /liabilities/*file          Assets.at("foo", file)
```

> you should add this to Build.scala:

```
playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "foo"
```

And this for using the reverse routing:

> However, if you define two mappings for the Assets.at action, like
>   this:

```
GET  /javascripts/*file        Assets.at("public/javascripts", file)
GET  /images/*file             Assets.at("public/images", file)
```

> Then you will need to specify both parameters when using the reverse
>   router:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("public/javascripts", "jquery.js")"></script>
<image src="@routes.Assets.at("public/images", "logo.png")">
```

**EDIT:**

Try to change your CSS link into this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("/public","stylesheets/bootstrap.css")">
```

Comment: Did you try calling your image like this `src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/images", "filename.png")"` ? If you did then the error must be somewhere else..